Next.js cookies client vs server
Problem: Unable to get cookies on a server component in next.js.  The cookie exists and I'm able to get it when running useEffect in a client component but when its accessed in a server component its always undefined.
    export default async function Category({ params: { locale, slug }, searchParams }: Props) {
  unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);

  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'Category' });
  const tPagination = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'Pagination' });
  const messages = await getMessages({ locale });

  const categoryId = Number(slug);

  const [{ category, categoryTree }, search] = await Promise.all([
    getCategoryPageData({ categoryId }),
    fetchFacetedSearch({ ...searchParams, category: categoryId }),
  ]);

  if (!category) {
    return notFound();
  }

  const productsCollection = search.products;
  const products = productsCollection.items;
  const { hasNextPage, hasPreviousPage, endCursor, startCursor } = productsCollection.pageInfo;
  const itemSkus = products.map((product) => ({ comp_no: product.sku }));

const storeId = cookies().get('storeId')
console.log('category page.tsx storeId: ', storeId)

  return (......)

I can see the cookie is there: chrome dev tools

server actions should only be used in form submissions, If you want to get the storeId cookie, you should probably separate the server actions from the getters, i'm supposing you are calling these getters inside the server component and not as a server actions, you can create a separate file called utils.(ts/js) or something else, and separate any getter function from server actions, i can see in your code that you don't have any server actions since they only accept a FormData parameter, so maybe you mean to use import "server-only" instead of "use server".

I probably included a bunch of details that were needed.  Even if I use the cookies().get('store") in the server component itself it returns undefined.  I'm only able to access it in the client.

I've tried reproducing with some test code, it works perfectly in a server component, can i know how you are setting the cookies, maybe the configuration?
